# Ktor proxy: forward all calls and add auth header

Tags: kotlin, ktor

i would like to implement a middelware proxy. Where all calls gets forwarded with an added header. This is what tried.

```
intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
    val targetUrl = BASE_URL + call.request.uri
    val response = client.request(targetUrl) {
        headers {
            append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $API_KEY")
        }
    }

    call.respond(response)
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run the code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: It dont work.  I get no errors. The request do not get forwarded.

Comment: The returned client response is of the `HttpResponse` type. The `ApplicationCall.respond` method doesn't know how to respond with this kind of object. You can find an example reverse proxy implementation here (https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/main/reverse-proxy).